# Explicitly subscribe a computed to an observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the following code, is there a way to explicitly subscribe `comp` to `b`, so that clicking `change a` and then `change b` would always fire `comp` (regardless how much times `change a` is clicked before `change b`)?

[Note that I'm not looking for a solution like taking `self.b()` out of the `else` block (or other similiar tricks), but rather an explicit call to some function, I guess something similiar to `subscribe`]

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.a = ko.observable(true);
  self.b = ko.observable(1);
  self.changeA = function () {
      console.log("changeA clicked");
      self.a(!self.a());
  }
  self.changeB = function () {
      console.log("changeB clicked");
      self.b(0);
  }

  self.comp = ko.computed(function () {
      if (!self.a()) {
          console.log("a");
          // ... some code that computes a ... 
      }
      else {
          console.log("b");
          var b = self.b();
          // ... some code that computes b ... 
      }
      return "hello";
  })
}
vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: changeA, text: 'change a'"></button>
<button data-bind="click: changeB, text: 'change b'"></button>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the behavior you're looking for and what's not working about the current code?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, the code works as it should according to dependency tracking rules - `b` is no more `comp`'s dependency once `change a` is clicked; But what I *want* is that it *would* be a dependency on any case, even after `change a` is clicked.

Comment: But its value won't change when b changes, so there is no effect. So what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, it's a code smell to have side effects in a computed. You should probably just be using a subscribe to both variables.

Comment: If using deferred updates is possible, then you can try deferring your `self.a` -> `self.a = ko.observable(true).extend({ deferred: true });`

Comment: @RoyJ, I don't mind its value won't change. I just want it to be called when clicking `change a` and than `change b`. I'll edit out the code smell.

Comment: @RoyJ, question editted.

Comment: If there are no side effects and the value doesn't change, you can just *pretend* it was called. Seriously, it sounds like you are trying to do something the wrong way, but you haven't said what you're trying to achieve, only how you want to achieve it. You could add `self.a.notifySubscribers()` to the `changeB` function. That should cause the computed to re-evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with using a subscriber and another observable?

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.a = ko.observable(true);
  self.b = ko.observable(1);

  self.changeA = function() {
    self.a(!self.a());
  }
  self.changeB = function() {
    self.b(0);
  }

  self.comp = ko.observable();

  self.b.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    console.log('b was changed to ', newVal);
    self.comp(newVal);
  })
}
vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: changeA, text: 'change a'"></button>
<button data-bind="click: changeB, text: 'change b'"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Roy J was right in his comments: The given code is a good sign for trying to do something the wrong way. I'll leave this question as a warning sign.